# Conexión segura con Sockets en Java

Tags: java, socket

tengo una duda acerca de una aplicación de escritorio que estoy creando en java, y es en la parte del login.

Resulta que no se como hacer el login seguro, lo hago mediante Sockets, pero la cuestión es que es una aplicación que será pública, entonces no se como usar Socket SSL sin usar una clave para todos, lo cual sería hackeable, podrían ayudarme?

Actualmente tengo este código para verlo en un ejemplo sencillo en un mensaje.

Para el servidor

```
//static ServerSocket variable
    private static ServerSocket server;
    //socket server port on which it will listen
    private static int port = 9876;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        //create the socket server object
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        //keep listens indefinitely until receives 'exit' call or program terminates
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Waiting for the client request");
            //creating socket and waiting for client connection
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            //read from socket to ObjectInputStream object
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //convert ObjectInputStream object to String
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
            //create ObjectOutputStream object
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            //write object to Socket
            oos.writeObject("Hi Client "+message);
            //close resources
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            socket.close();
            //terminate the server if client sends exit request
            if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
        }
        System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");
        //close the ServerSocket object
        server.close();
    }

}
```

Para el cliente

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{
        //get the localhost IP address, if server is running on some other IP, you need to use that
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket socket = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
            //establish socket connection to server
            socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 9876);
            //write to socket using ObjectOutputStream
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Sending request to Socket Server");
            if(i==4)oos.writeObject("exit");
            else oos.writeObject(""+i);
            //read the server response message
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message: " + message);
            //close resources
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Hola! Para hacer una pregunt sobre tu código, comparte los fragmentos relevantes de tu código y lo que has intentado hacer para resolver tu problema.

Comment: Listo, ya lo e solucionado, lo lamento.